# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 6553612 byte allocation with 3696144 free bytes and 3MB until OOM

Tags: android

When I load my EmojiActivity, it loads the corresponding layout:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_emoji);
```

That layout has a `GridLayout` with 25 `ImageView`'s.

```
<GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:columnCount="5"
        android:rowCount="5">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:src="@drawable/grinning_emoji_with_smiling_eyes" />
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:src="@drawable/hugging_face_emoji" />
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:src="@drawable/hungry_face_emoji" />
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:src="@drawable/kiss_emoji_with_closed_eyes" />
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:src="@drawable/kissing_face_emoji" />


    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:src="@drawable/kissing_face_with_smiling_eyes_emoji" />
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:src="@drawable/money_face_emoji" />
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:src="@drawable/nerd_with_glasses_emoji" />
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:src="@drawable/relieved_emoji" />
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:src="@drawable/sad_face_emoji" />


    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:src="@drawable/slightly_smiling_face_emoji" />
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:src="@drawable/smiling_emoji_with_eyes_opened" />
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:src="@drawable/smiling_emoji_with_smiling_eyes" />
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:src="@drawable/smiling_face_emoji" />
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:src="@drawable/smiling_face_emoji_with_blushed_cheeks" />


    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:src="@drawable/smiling_face_with_closed_eyes" />
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:src="@drawable/smiling_with_sweat_emoji" />
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:src="@drawable/smirk_face_emoji" />
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:src="@drawable/sunglasses_emoji" />
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="3"
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:src="@drawable/tears_of_joy_emoji" />


    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:src="@drawable/tongue_out_emoji" />
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:src="@drawable/tongue_out_emoji_with_closed_eyes" />
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:src="@drawable/tongue_out_emoji_with_winking_eye" />
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_column="3"
            android:src="@drawable/unamused_face_emoji" />
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_row="4"
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:src="@drawable/upside_down_face_emoji" />
</GridLayout>
```

The graphics are located in @drawable and their total size is 2.4 megabytes on disk. Each of them is around 100 kilobytes. So I have no idea why a out of memory error would occur with such a light load:

```
I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc
I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 140MB to 128MB
I/art: Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(96B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 3% free, 124MB/128MB, paused 668us total 18.401ms
W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 6553612 byte allocation with 4109776 free bytes and 3MB until OOM"
D/skia: --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: mobapptut.com.camera2videoimage, PID: 30354
                  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 6553612 byte allocation with 4109776 free bytes and 3MB until OOM
                      at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
                      at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
                      at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2738)
                      at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2643)
                      at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:870)
                      at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:152)
                      at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:140)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:57)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1013)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1072)
                      at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                      at mobapptut.com.camera2videoimage.EmojiActivity.onCreate(EmojiActivity.java:11)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6272)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2494)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:157)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1356)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
I/art: Clamp target GC heap from 132MB to 128MB
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 30354 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
```

I am attempting to create snapchat clone and in snapchat they are loading 25 emoji's on the screen. I am using images of small sizes. So what is going on?

Comment: You are obviously out of memory. Are you also out of memory when not running the application?

Comment: I am able to run snapchat fine. And I am able to load the my Camera2 implementation which is part of my app. Only when I click on a button and load this particular activity does the app crash.

Comment: You do not say if you have sufficient memory prior starting your application. You need an accurate number on this.

Comment: According to memory on my device, it says 459 MB of free memory when application is not running.

Comment: The problem is that the heap space might not be sufficient despite this memory available, it says `124MB/128MB` so you only have 128MB and it seems that something out there or within your code is consuming this... Memory leak?

Comment: Memory leak from what? I run  mCameraDevice.close() before I move to the next activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Each of them is around 100 kilobytes

Images stored on disk are compressed, at least for the relevant formats for Android resources. The size in memory is based on the *uncompressed* size (width x height x 4 bytes/pixel)... at best.

> The graphics are located in @drawable

If by this you mean `res/drawable/`, that is a synonym for `res/drawable-mdpi/`. Putting images there tells Android to resample those images when running on other-density devices. So, for example, if you are running on an `-xhdpi` device, the bitmap will consume four times the heap space that it would on an `-mdpi` device.

> That layout has a GridLayout with 25 ImageView's.

100KB of a compressed image is a rather large image. A PNG, for example, would be somewhere around 800x600 pixels. There is no way that you are going to fit 25 of those on one screen at a time.

So, to fix this:

- Use lower-resolution images
- Put them in a proper directory, based on the actual density, not `res/drawable/`

Comment: I resized them to 50x50 which saved as 5KB and it worked.